# Android - Does every brand which is using android as a platfrom in their mobiles has different list of core processes?

Tags: android, process

I am wondering that does every brand out there whose manufacturing android phones like HTC, Samsung, LG, Motorola etc has different list of their core processes like HTC has com.htc.launcher, Samsung has com.sec.android.app.samsung etc.

If yes then i have two questions.

1. Why they have different processes when default android processes are enough to perform necessary tasks.
2. Can some one provide me this lists of processes or give me a small idea about where to get these lists of processes as its always good to know about this kind of stuff if you are in mobile development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why they have different processes when default android processes are enough to perform necessary tasks.

You have no idea what "the necessary tasks" are, since you did not create those devices, since you are apparently not an employee at any of those firms.

Furthermore, equipment manufacturers have been developing software for their equipment, and shipping it with their equipment, since the invention of the computer. That was quite some time ago.

If you do not want these "different processes", you are welcome to build your own firmware, or use firmware from an existing third party, that runs on your phone.

> Can some one provide me this lists of processes or give me a small idea about where to get these lists of processes

You are welcome to get a job at those firms where you can work on their devices and learn how they work.

> its always good to know about this kind of stuff if you are in mobile development.

You are welcome to your opinion. I do not share it.

Comment: first book i read about android was written by you. It was Beginning Android 2 and published by Apress and i simply love your writting style. You are a self employed person who has a big name in Android world. On the other side i am a paid servant and i am getting paid for what i know. So the basic reason behind why i want to know this kind of stuff is that if i know more i'll get paid more and may be promoted some day. I hope you will understand my situation.

Comment: @Varundroid: You are welcome to learn anything you can about the open source base Android OS. Device manufacturers, and ordinary people like you, are welcome to make changes to that OS for their own devices and not disclose the nature of those changes. If you wish to learn more about what they wrote and why they wrote it, you will need to go get a job with them working on the team that writes this software. I suppose you could try taking people hostage and demand this information at gunpoint, but I really would prefer that you did not exercise this option. :-)

Comment: LOL there is no way i am going to exercise this option.
Still thanks for your advise :-)